# gcc compiler ignores uninitialized variable warning for debug build

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

`gcc` compiler ignores `uninitialized variable warning` for debug build. This looks very weird for me, can some one help me to understand this ?

```
## Program  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, max;
    int count;
    if (argc < 2) {
        return -1;
    }
    max = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("count is %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

### gcc a.c -g -Wall -Werror

No warning

### gcc a.c -O3 -Wall -Werror

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:8:9: error: ‘count’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
     int count;
         ^~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

`gcc` version: 7.4.0

Comment: Some static code analysis is done during optimization. So certain warnings will only be available when a certain optimization level is set. This is one of the cases.

Comment: Why not use `gcc a.c -O3 -g -Wall -Werror` (and throw in `-Wextra` while you're at it, and maybe some other warning flags).  That gets you the best of both worlds — debugging information and optimization.  I use this combination most of the time.  It does mean that if you have to run the debugger, you might get slightly peculiar behaviour as code is moved or removed by the optimizer.  But it does work most of the time.  If you're in for a serious debugging session, drop the `-O3` — otherwise, use both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though it may look weird, this behavior is [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` gcc option:

> `-Wmaybe-uninitialized`
>
> For an automatic (i.e. local) variable, if there exists a path from the function entry to a use of the variable that is initialized, but there exist some other paths for which the variable is not initialized, the compiler emits a warning if it cannot prove the uninitialized paths are not executed at run time.
>
> These warnings are only possible in optimizing compilation, because otherwise GCC does not keep track of the state of variables.

I guess the reason is that the cost of analyzing not initialized variables is too much for not optimizing compilation. That's why it is done only for optimizing one.