# gcc compiler not giving -Wuninitialized warning sometimes

Tags: c++, g++

I am running below simple program where i have not initialized variable x2 and then trying to use it in main() function. I am expecting Wuninitialized warning from compiler but do not get it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Obj
{
    int x1;
    int x2;

    Obj() : x1(0) {}
};

int main()
{
    Obj obj;
    cout << obj.x1 << endl;
    cout << obj.x2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine without any warning - g++ --std=c++17 -Wall abc.cpp

If i don't initialize both x1 and x2, i get the expected warnings.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Obj
{
    int x1;
    int x2;

//    Obj() : x1(0) {}
};

int main()
{
    Obj obj;
    cout << obj.x1 << endl;
    cout << obj.x2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now i do get warnings.

```
g++ --std=c++17 -Wall abc.cpp
abc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
abc.cpp:16:17: warning: ‘obj.Obj::x1’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   16 |     cout << obj.x1 << endl;
      |                 ^~
abc.cpp:17:17: warning: ‘obj.Obj::x2’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   17 |     cout << obj.x2 << endl;
      |                 ^~
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I am expecting Wuninitialized warning in both the cases.

Comment: same question for C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687623/gcc-compiler-ignores-uninitialized-variable-warning-for-debug-build

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'd consider that a proper duplicate

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili Indeed. In my answer I assumed obscure reasons, but the docs are actually very clear

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai [clang doesn't warn at all](https://godbolt.org/z/rj8fsjd3d). One more reason to test on both compilers.